# Highcharts: align markers with xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have a type `area` chart, with minor grid lines and a `datetime` xAxis. `data` is feed through an array of y values, and I got to render xAxis labels depending on the `data` length successfully.

My issues are:

- the chart has a unwanted padding on the X axis
- the markers don't align with their labels

Check it:

[image]
Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fernandaparisi/e07q32ay/53/

I noticed that if I remove all the `max`, `min`, `tickInterval`, `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties the markers are aligned correctly, but the chart doesn't expand its full available width.

`margin` and `spacing` chart properties seem to affect the chart as a whole, and not the plotted area.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. The padding is caused by combined `tickInterval` and `endOnTick: true`, to remove it just disable `endOnTick`.
2. To position the labels in a different way use `align`, `x` and `y` properties.

---

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        align: 'center',
        y: 30,
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b', this.value);
        },
        rotation: -45
    },
    title: undefined,
    type: 'datetime',
    min: lastSunday - (weekLength * (data.length - 1)),
    max: lastSunday,
    tickInterval: weekLength,
    endOnTick: false,
    minorTickInterval: weekLength
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eLbp48d3/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.labels.align

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.endOnTick